# Package signing/verification passes on Ubuntu 16.04 but fails on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, apt, package-management, dpkg

I am trying to implement a signing and verification process of deb packages.

This is what i am doing:

1. **Generate GPG Keys** ([tutorial](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/c14.html))
2. **Sign the package:**

   ```
   $ dpkg-sig -k F4C52DDF --sign builder client.deb 
   Processing client.deb...
   You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for user: "Foo Bar <foo@bar.com>"
   2048-bit RSA key, ID F4C52DDF, created 2018-03-13
   Signed deb client.deb
   ```
3. **Verify the Package:**

   ```
   $ dpkg-sig --verify client.deb
   Processing client.deb
   GOODSIG _gpgbuilder 3910701E538E37B3F93B8FCC7570E500F4C52DDF 1520919017
   ```

When i run these steps on Ubuntu 16.04, i get a GOODSIG message but when i try to run these exact same steps on Ubuntu 14.04, i get `BADSIG _gpgbuilder`.

Can anyone help me in figuring out whats the issue? I cant seem to find much help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this myself in case anyone else runs into this issue.

Turns out, there was a bug in dpkg-sig that was patched later on (details on: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg-sig/+bug/1342938)

The issue is that there are two compression types that dpkg uses while building deb packages: gz and xz. The bug was that dpkg-sig only checked for data.tar.gz while verifying the signature and it failed/returned badsig on data.tar.xz. In my case, the xz compression method was used to build the package that i was testing on.

The bug has now been patched and the updated dpkg-sig deb package can be downloaded from: http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/d/dpkg-sig/dpkg-sig_0.13.1+nmu4_all.deb

This issue was occurring in Ubuntu 14.04 because when downloading from the apt-repository, we get the older, non patched version of dpkg-sig. So if anyone on Ubuntu 14.04 runs into this issue, they can simply download the updated deb package from the ftp url given above and it should solve their problem.

As an additional note, you can check the compression type by doing the following on terminal:

```
ar vx packagename.deb
```

You should get get either data.tar.gz or data.tar.xz alongwith some other files. This should help you in figuring out what the compression type is.

**Another helpful Reference:** https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2175836